# Suppress HuggingFace logging warning: "Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:{eos_token_id} for open-end generation."

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

In HuggingFace, every time I call a `pipeline()` object, I get a warning:

```
`"Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:{eos_token_id} for open-end generation."
```

How do I suppress this warning without suppressing all logging warnings? I want other warnings, but I don't want this one.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The warning comes for any text generation task done by HuggingFace. This is explained [here](https://jaketae.github.io/study/gpt2/#setup), and you can see the code [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/b880508440f43f80e35a78ccd2a32f3bde91cb23/src/transformers/generation_utils.py#L410-L414). You can avoid that warning by manually setting the `pad_token_id` to the `eos_token_id`.

That is when you call

> ```py
> model.generate(**encoded_input)
> ```

just change it to

> ```py
> model.generate(**encoded_input, pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)
> ```

and that will get rid of the error. However, I haven't found a way to set this directly from the pipeline interface. I'm guessing you could pass in some arguments to the ArgumentHandler. But I haven't tried it.

Comment: What other effects would changing the PAD token to the EOS token have?

Comment: why doesn't this just get set automaticly from the models configuration?

Answer (score 11):

For a [text-generation pipeline](https://huggingface.co/gpt2#how-to-use), you need to set the `pad_token_id` in the `generator` call to suppress the warning:

```py
from transformers import pipeline

generator = pipeline('text-generation', model='gpt2')
sample = generator('test test', pad_token_id=generator.tokenizer.eos_token_id)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "to suppress the output". @chicxulub

Comment: I meant not having the generator print out the warning mentioned in the question: "Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:{eos_token_id} for open-end generation." I'll edit the answer to clarify that

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot access the `generate` call to add the `pad_token_id` parameter as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71397707/1643939) you can also set it in the generation config of the model like this:

```py
model.generation_config.pad_token_id = model.generation_config.eos_token_id
```

Example for GPT-2:

```py
gpt2 = transformers.AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained('gpt2')
tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')

gpt2.generation_config.pad_token_id = gpt2.generation_config.eos_token_id

model_inputs = tokenizer("foo", return_tensors='pt')
model_outputs = gpt2.generate(**model_inputs, max_new_tokens=20)
print(tokenizer.decode(model_outputs[0]))
```